# Redis arabic language decoding

Tags: redis, phpredis, redis-cli

I use Redis with PHP, with phpRedis connector.
When i save a word in arabic language I can't retrieve this word, it's return encoding values.

In redis the problem is solved if I connect with: >redis-cli --raw

Example here:

amic:/var/www/core-bitercash$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> set xx جيد
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> get xx
"\xd8\xac\xd9\x8a\xd8\xaf"

amic:/var/www/core-bitercash$ redis-cli --raw
127.0.0.1:6379> get xx
جيد
127.0.0.1:6379>

Yes it's work, but for phpRedis is don't work.
Is return:
Ø¬ÙŠØ¯

the value saved in redis.

I don't know how to connect with --raw option for phpRedis lib or haw to decode the text "Ø¬ÙŠØ" in php.

Comment: this is certainly a client problem, redis itself is encoding agnostic. You can, if you want, url-encode the texts and decode them when getting them back to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the key in Redis as you posted in your question, save this code as `test.php` on your webserver and open the page in your browser, do the chars show up correctly ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
echo $redis->get('xx');
?>
</body>
</html>
```

If that fails to work, include this code at the beginning of the page:

```
<?php ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8'); ?>
```

Comment: yes, it's works. I think my problem was when retrieve data from MySQL with PDO.  I change PDO conexion to:  $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD, $options = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8']);